# C++ IDE for Macs

Tags: c++, macos, ide

I teach a C++ course using Visual Studio.  One of my students has a Mac and was looking for an IDE to use on his machine. What would be good to recommend?

Comment: [Clion IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) Clion is the way to go.

Comment: To me eclipse c++ ide is the best ... i've even test Clion, I think eclipse is better than clion.

Comment: Xcode is the best..
I dont find any editor bette than XCODE
Even i have write assembly language code in XCODE

Comment: CodeLite is an alternative to Xcode. It is open-source and cross-platform.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/) which is part of the MacOS Developer Tools is a great IDE. There's also [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org) and [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) that can be configured to build and compile C++ projects.

[Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) from JetBrains, also is available now, and uses Cmake as project model.

Comment: (rhetorical) how can you beat Xcode as the answer to JohnMcG's question? you can't!  Xcode is FREE (to mac owners), and while it simplifies and streamlines what gcc and gdb are doing for you, it **is** built on gnu, so you can easily "drop down a level" to straight gcc and gdb at any time!

Comment: Xcode doesn't have refactoring support on OSX. Or at least it was disabled on my system.. so I use eclipse for now.

Comment: I also have to say that I like the fonts in Xcode much more, they look kinda wired in eclipse..

Comment: I never noticed a significant enough different in font rendering between Xcode and Eclipse. Xcode's layout, however, is weird. Especially if he was using Visual C++ to teach the class. Eclipse or Netbeans would be a much better option.

Comment: Xcode pwns NetBeans and Eclipse combined. And @que @que Xcode is not free, it costs $4.55.

Comment: @WTP my XCode came bundled with the OS, are you talking about the XCode4? I think the free one is good-to-go for C++

Comment: XCode is very sluggish on my mac with SSD and 8GB RAM, I am really looking for some substitution for C++ projects.

Comment: Xcode's C++ autocompletion is lacking, it is slow and can't refactor C++. So maybe it's good as an IDE, but it's had as a text editor.

Comment: Xcode is a C++ IDE just as much a notepad is.

Comment: Xcode is really a bad IDE, you can't even format the code. It's better TextEdit.

Comment: As much as I love Xcode for Objective-C, it is HORRIBLE for C++ development. You can't get even a distant similarity of Visual Studio's autocompletion, refactoring, jump-to-definition/declaration, method lookups and all those other features that speed up development radically. Xcode even looses syntax coloring from time to time and stops doing trivial code completion until restarted(!). I've been writing C++ code in OSX for few years already and my dev environment is spread between Sublime and Xcode. I haven't found a genuine OSX IDE (not Java-written like Eclipse or NetBeans) similar to VS.

Comment: Xcode 9 added support for refactoring C++ (along with Swift).

Comment: I would go for either code blocks or netbeans as they are open-source and cross platform. Eclipse has always been buggy, I do not recommend using it.

Comment: I just wanted to warn people from Eclipse, it's quite glitchy on Big Sur and Catalina. It still works with older versions, though.

Comment: Clion is a good IDE,but it is not free.

Answer (score 15):

Emacs!  Eclipse might work too.

Comment: Yes. It feels like an Integrated Development Environment to me!

Comment: I thought emacs was an OS

Comment: emacs is an ide, an OS, an email/news reader and whatever else you want it to be. https://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html

Answer (score 7):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is cross-platform, using the [wxWidgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets) library. It's the one I use.

Comment: Plus, it's unstable on Mac.

Comment: Just tried this on a mac it's not great

Comment: confirm. we use it in some labs, (I am a teacher) but stability, use and crash are simple NOT comparable. go Xcode. (it's free).

Answer (score 5):

Another (albeit non-free) option is to install VMware Fusion or Parallels Desktop on the Mac and run Windows with Visual Studio in a VM.

This works really pretty well.  The downsides are:

- it'll cost money for the virtual machine software and Windows (the school may have some academic licensing that may help here)
- the Mac needs to be an x86 Mac with a fair bit of memory

The upside is that you and the student don't need to hassle with differences in the IDE that may not be accounted for in your instruction materials.

Comment: Worth mentioning that with your method he will be building Windows binaries, and he _may_ want to build MacOS binaries instead.

Comment: He could use virtual box which is free.

Comment: That's what I do most of the time, but it's annoying...

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a full-fledged IDE like Visual Studio,
I think Eclipse might be your best bet.

Eclipse is also highly extensible and configurable.

See here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 4):

Of​​​​​ course there is [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)).

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an IDE per se, but I really like TextMate, and with the C++ bundle that ships with it, it can do a lot of the things you'd find in an IDE (without all the bloat!).

Comment: I agree, unlike XCode, emacs etc. it's not free though...

Comment: @Pieter Not anymore. It is now GPL 3. http://blog.macromates.com/2012/textmate-2-at-github/

Answer (score 1):

Avoid [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) for C/C++ development for now on [Mac OS X v10.6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) (Snow Leopard). There are serious problems which make debugging problematic or nearly impossible on it currently due to [GDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) incompatibility problems and the like. See: *[Trouble debugging C++ using Eclipse Galileo on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270285/trouble-debugging-c-using-eclipse-galileo-on-mac)*.

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/) is free and good, which is lucky because it's pretty much the only option on the Mac.

Comment: Eclipse is also an option but XCode is also good.