# sublime text mac os development

Tags: c++, python, sublimetext2

I really like SublimeText2 on Mac OS X.

From wikipedia, it seems like this is build with python and C++.
How can I use python and C++ to develop for Mac OS X?
Can you use Python in XCode or is there any other environment to develop as mac desktop app?

Please teach me how.
Thank you.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276967/python-in-xcode-4, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220644/c-ide-for-macs, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722894/best-c-ide-for-mac-os-x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use python and C++ to develop on OS X. Python and C++ are both capable of being developed using XCode. I would recommend XCode for C++ ([Complete solution for writing Mac OS X application in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634404/complete-solution-for-writing-mac-os-x-application-in-c)). As for python, you can use XCode, but it might be a bit heavy. I use vim for python but vim isn't for everyone so I would also recommend Wing IDE 101 (http://wingware.com/downloads/wingide-101/4.1.9-1/binaries). I used it for a while with great success.

Comment: Thanks! You gave me the exact answer I was looking for!